# Window and Textbox as argument in function

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, window

I have to write a function for WPF application:

```
public void function(Window win)
{
    win.mytextbox.Text=""; // will show error
}
```

Called argument Window's will have `mytextbox` in all of them, but how do I set value in function as win doesnt have `mytextbox` ?

Function will be called in `MainWindow` only where all window instance are present i.e win1, win2, win3,.. and all and function is also in `MainWindow`?

Comment: Don't call it "function"... These are object-methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the name of you TextBox is "mytextbox" you can access it through

```
((TextBox)win.FindName("mytextbox")).Text = "";
```

You could also pass the MainWindow as argument and then access mytextbox directly, like so:

```
public void MyFunction(MainWindow mw)
{
    mw.mytextbox.Text = "";
}
```

Since you are using WPF, you should consider using [DataBinding](http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html) instead of manipulating your Controls properties in code-behind.

Comment: just out of curiosity there is no way to use directly mytextbox in above function ?

Comment: only if you pass it as argument, but in the example above, youre accessing the same instance of the TextBox as with `mytextbox.Text = "";` so there is no difference.